# Javascript: Schema Explorer Chrome Extension loop needs to ignore irrelevant nested elements

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, schema.org

This should be **easy for a Javascript expert**.

For those who don't know what schema is ( http://schema.org ), it's a new way for Search Engines to read content on a webpage. It works by tagging relevant data with specific tags.

For those who do know what it is, here is a chrome extension ([Schema Explorer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/docnladpefffgdocnidfngejcagdkedb)) that makes it easy to inspect what your data looks like on your page. See the example.

**NOW:** There is a tiny issue with the extension where by is does not skip/ignore empty nested elements. Here are two examples: **The first works** perfectly but, **the second bombs** because of the empty `<div>` tag:

**First example works:**

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie">
   <h1 itemprop="name">Avatar</h1>
   <div itemprop="director" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
      Director: <span itemprop="name">James Cameron</span> (born <span itemprop="birthDate">August 16, 1954</span>)
   </div>
   <span itemprop="genre">Science fiction</span>
   <a href="http://pierreloicdoulcet.fr/movies/avatar-theatrical-trailer.html" itemprop="trailer">Trailer</a>
</div>
```

**Seconds example gives issues:**

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie">
   <div>
     <h1 itemprop="name">Avatar</h1>
     <div itemprop="director" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
         Director: <span itemprop="name">James Cameron</span> (born <span itemprop="birthDate">August 16, 1954</span>)
     </div>
     <span itemprop="genre">Science fiction</span>
     <a href="http://pierreloicdoulcet.fr/movies/avatar-theatrical-trailer.html" itemprop="trailer">Trailer</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

I had a look at the extension and it's actually very well put together with one javascript file doing most of the work. Here is the code that does the looping, **however** it needs to be able to skip empty nested elements and **perhaps be a little bit more robust in general**:

```
    var __explore = function(node, parentData)
    {
        if (parentData === null || parentData === undefined)
        {
            parentData = __dataTree;
        }
        if (node.getAttribute)
        {
            var isItemScope = node.getAttribute('itemscope');
            var hasItemProp = node.getAttribute('itemprop');
            var itemtype = node.getAttribute('itemtype');


            var childs = node.childNodes;

            var i = 0;

            var tmp = new Array();

            while (i < childs.length)
            {
                if (isItemScope !== null)
                    __explore(childs[i], tmp);
                else
                    __explore(childs[i], null);
                ++i;
            }

            if (isItemScope !== null)
            {
                parentData.push({name : 'scope', value : hasItemProp, type : itemtype, childs : [tmp], node : node});
            }
            else if (hasItemProp && parentData)
            {
                parentData.push({name : hasItemProp, value :  node.innerText});
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the complete versions of the `contentscript.js` https://gist.github.com/3413475

Hopefully someone can help me with this. For the record I've contacted the author but he's been preoccupied with more urgent matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/vyrvp/1/ but I must confess that this is a bit hackish. This code may need some more refactoring to make it work for all cases and make it readable.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look and see if it in fact works on larger testbeds.